# Why do I see a slightly zoomed version of the image on the iPhone camera compared to what is received at the backend server?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone

I am capturing the image from the iOS camera on the iPhone7 and sending the captured camera image to the backend for processing.

When I save the image at the backend, I see that the backend image has lot more content than that what was visible on the iOS screen when focusing on the object.

The server image is a zoomed out version with little extra content on the horitonal and vertical axis on both the sides. I verified that I am not doing any explicit zooming or anything like that in the Objective-C code.

The question is what is causing this difference in what I see on the screen v/s what gets received at the backend.

The code that I use to capture the image is

```
-(UIImage *) imageFromSamplePlanerPixelBuffer:(CMSampleBufferRef) sampleBuffer{

@autoreleasepool {
    // Get a CMSampleBuffer's Core Video image buffer for the media data
    CVImageBufferRef imageBuffer = CMSampleBufferGetImageBuffer(sampleBuffer);
    // Lock the base address of the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferLockBaseAddress(imageBuffer, 0);


    size_t width = CVPixelBufferGetWidth(imageBuffer);
    size_t height = CVPixelBufferGetHeight(imageBuffer);

    uint8_t *baseAddress = (uint8_t*) CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddress(imageBuffer);
    uint8_t *yBuffer = (uint8_t*) CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    uint8_t *cbCrBuffer = (uint8_t*) CVPixelBufferGetBaseAddressOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1);
    size_t yPitch = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 0);
    size_t cbCrPitch = CVPixelBufferGetBytesPerRowOfPlane(imageBuffer, 1);

    int bytesPerPixel = 4;
    uint8_t *rgbBuffer = (uint8_t*)malloc(width * height * bytesPerPixel);

    for(int y = 0; y < height; y++)
    {
        uint8_t *rgbBufferLine = &rgbBuffer[y * width * bytesPerPixel];
        uint8_t *yBufferLine = &yBuffer[y * yPitch];
        uint8_t *cbCrBufferLine = &cbCrBuffer[(y >> 1) * cbCrPitch];

        for(int x = 0; x < width; x++)
        {
            int16_t y = yBufferLine[x];
            int16_t cb = cbCrBufferLine[x & ~1] - 128;
            int16_t cr = cbCrBufferLine[x | 1] - 128;

            uint8_t *rgbOutput = &rgbBufferLine[x*bytesPerPixel];

            int16_t r = (int16_t)roundf( y + cr *  1.4 );
            int16_t g = (int16_t)roundf( y + cb * -0.343 + cr * -0.711 );
            int16_t b = (int16_t)roundf( y + cb *  1.765);

            rgbOutput[0] = 0xFF;
            rgbOutput[1] = clamp(b);
            rgbOutput[2] = clamp(g);
            rgbOutput[3] = clamp(r);
        }


// Create a device-dependent RGB color space
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    // Create a bitmap graphics context with the sample buffer data
    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(rgbBuffer, width, height, 8, width * bytesPerPixel, colorSpace, kCGBitmapByteOrder32Little | kCGImageAlphaNoneSkipLast);
    // Create a Quartz image from the pixel data in the bitmap graphics context
    CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);



    // Unlock the pixel buffer
    CVPixelBufferUnlockBaseAddress(imageBuffer,0);

    // Free up the context and color space
    CGContextRelease(context);
    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    // Create an image object from the Quartz image
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage scale:0.5f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];


    NSData *imgData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(image, 0.8);

    NSLog(@"blabla %lu", (unsigned long)[imgData length]);
    // Release the Quartz image
    free(rgbBuffer);

    CGImageRelease(quartzImage);

    return (image);
```

Comment: Are you applying any gravity? `avLayer.videoGravity = AVLayerVideoGravityResizeAspectFill;` or something like this?

Comment: @AdilSoomro Now I am not using anything like that. Should I?

Comment: Are you using native UIImagePickerController or you've custom code for camera?

Comment: @AdilSoomroI have custom code given to me that uses CMSampleBuffer, CGImageRef and so on

Comment: The code I have is these important lines:   CGImageRef quartzImage = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context); and UIImage *image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:quartzImage scale:1.0f orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];

Comment: You should edit your question and post related code there.

Comment: @AdilSoomro done above . Added the bit of the code responsible for capturing the image

Comment: How are you setting up your AVLayer?

Comment: @AdilSoomro I just updated the complete method. Please do take a look. I am just unable to understand why is the image at the backend having more pixels on the height side compared to what I see on the screen on front end. Thanks

Comment: See, the code you posted is entirely related to how you get the image from camera and then process it. The code which I'm asking is related to showing camera image on screen. There must be some AVLayer, or some AVFoundation classes that're being used to show camera feed on UIView.

Comment: let me check @AdilSoomro.